# Threading in php in a web server environment

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am not pretty familiar with PHP threads, as long as I am searching for options for using threads in PHP, the most suitable tool I can find is [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php).  Though it is very convenient to use, it requires ZTS and it is clearly mentioned in the documents that this tool cannot be used in a web server environment.

> **Warning** The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server
>   environment. Threading in PHP is therefore restricted to CLI-based
>   applications only.

So I was wondering what is the best way to use threads or multi threads in an web server environment in PHP.

Comment: may I ask if you don't mind, where will you apply this multi threading?

Comment: Where as in what context?

Comment: I need to send noitifications to various mobile apps from a php laravel api using firebase. Before sending notification, I have to check if the current device is online, then I will send notification to this device. This whole process must be asynchronous.

Comment: That seems to be something that doesn't necessarily needs to happen within the web app it self. I would start by having a look at a queueing system, the idea is simple, my web app could send messages to it so they can be processed by an external (async) job, in this case the process that will do the online check, and ultimately send the notification to the device afterwards.

Comment: I would like to flush log to disk, so I get something saved when fpm kills the process because of timeout

Answer (score -1):

Yaba daba don't.

Why not? Because other languages do threads better.

What you want to do can be done with a worker that consumes events from a queue. This is how we do things in the PHP world.

Essentially you run another PHP process somewhere else (from a cron job, for example) that does your background processing. The web-related (fpm) workers should be as light weight as possible and only submit these tasks or events to the queue.

Multi threading (not actually) with PHP is achieved by a http server sending multiple requests to a php-fpm daemon (or mod_php if you are so inclined) and by running schedulers or workers in the background as separate, independent processes.

Comment: if you _really_ want to experiment with it... no one is stopping you from compiling php with threads and building your own server in PHP with sockets and so on... 
some crazies have done this in the past: https://github.com/youngj/httpserver

Comment: allthouth that one is maybe not a "real" server since it's cgi based, idk..